# Confusion in Proteus

Tags: simulation, proteus

I have made a 12.7 V AC to 5 V DC using 7805 in Proteus.

I connected channel A of the oscilloscope to the input of the bridge and it gives me 12.7 volts peak which is the amplitude of the source as well and there is no problem with that (shown in the figure).

The problem I face is that when I connect the channel D of the oscilloscope to the input of the 7805 I hope to get 11.32 V DC with some ripples but what I am getting is this graph of ripples in millivolts as shown in the figure as well.

Why is so when theoretically the voltage on the input of 7805 should be 12.7 - 1.4 = 11.32 Volts?

[image: 1]

Comment: Why are you shorting ground generator and ground 7805? Don't put the ground generator. Let it "fly".

Comment: Fly meaning? I shouldn't ground the source and 7805?

Comment: By grounding both one side of the AC source and the DC negative you are shorting one of the diodes in the bridge rectifier.

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: @Alex you should decide what your “ground” reference is. Is it the blue wire in your AC plug, or is it the lower voltage for your regulator?

Comment: Example: Right now one of the diodes contents ground to ground. Why is that useful?

Comment: … Please use your Operating systems "Screenshot" functionality! Your keyboard might even have a dedicated button for it, PrintScr. Reading such camera screenshots is just unnecessarily unsatisfying.